# Predeclaring Multidimensional Character Column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multidimensional-array, character

I would like to declare a column in a data.frame that is a multidimensional character array (3 characters in each row).  I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure this out.

```
    simulations <- 1000
    data <- data.frame(nonsing = character(simulations))
    
    for(i in 1:simulations){
      data$nonsing[i] = letters[1:3]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collapse the 3 characters in one string which can be done with `toString`.

```
simulations <- 1000
data <- data.frame(nonsing = character(simulations))

for(i in 1:simulations){
  data$nonsing[i] = toString(letters[sample(1:26, 3)])
}
```

`letters[1:3]` would always give `'a, b, c'` hence I used `sample` to assign random 3 letters.

---

You can also use `replicate` :

```
data$nonsing <- replicate(simulations, toString(letters[sample(1:26, 3)]))
```